# Temporarily declare a word as wrong in vim spellchecker

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I'm writing a document with vim and latex. I recently noticed a word that I use ("tree"), but which is incorrect in the context of my document. I corrected it on the whole document. However, I have the habit to use this word instead of the correct one, when writing.

Is it possible to declare this word as a temporary wrong word (until the buffer is closed, this is enough), to make the spell-checker highlight it?

I have tried to mark it as definitive wrong word. This is not a solution as "tree" is in fact a correct word and should not be highlight in other documents. I also tried to search it: my vim is configured to automatically highlight it when I write it. This is a half-solution, as it needs that my last search be "tree", and handles difficultly many words if I have really wrong habits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim spell cheat sheet:

- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> / <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> - next / previous misspelled word
- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> - next / previous bad word (i.e. as above, but ignore rare words and the like)
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> - add good word to the first dictionary in `spellfile`; remove it with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - add good word to the internal wordlist; remove it with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - add bad word to the first dictionary; remove it with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> - add bad word to the internal wordlist; remove it with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> - suggest correctly spelled word.

According to the documentation,

> The internal word list is used for all buffers where 'spell' is set.  It is
>   not stored, it is lost when you exit Vim.  It is also cleared when 'encoding'
>   is set.

So this is what you are looking for.

Please see `:help spell-quickstart` for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `match` in your buffer, which will vanish when you close it.

```
:match Error /tree/
```

To only match the whole word "tree", use `\<` to match the beginning of the word and `\>` to match the end.

```
:match Error /\<tree\>/
```

`:match` documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:match